# Gstreamer-sharp running on Linux

Tags: c#, mono, gstreamer, gtk#

since I'm currently working on a gstreamer binding for my project and got the information, that gstreamer-sharp 0.99.x is only working with glib-sharp 2.99.x, I thought it a good idea to create a test project. So I downloaded the addin for monodevelop named "GTK# 3 Simple Project Template" and compiled it -> worked. Now I added the gstreamer-sharp 0.99 dll I compiled before and added the following code:

```
Gst.Application.Init();
Element music = Parse.Launch("playbin uri=\"file:////media/Auslagerung/DJ/IDs/android.mp3\"");
music.SetState(Gst.State.Playing);
```

I get the following exception, when I play this code:

```
Marshaling clicked signal
Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gst.Pipeline ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gst.Pipeline:gstsharp_gst_pipeline_get_fixed_clock_offset ()
  at Gst.Pipeline..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:537 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00013] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:543 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000a5] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:528 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:556 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00174] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:301 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:238 
  at GLib.ObjectManager.CreateObject (IntPtr raw) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Object.GetObject (IntPtr o, Boolean owned_ref) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Object.GetObject (IntPtr o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gst.Parse.Launch (System.String pipeline_description) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MainWindow.onButtonClick (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs a) [0x00039] in /media/Auslagerung/tmp/Gtk3-Sharp-Test/Gtk3-Sharp-Test/MainWindow.cs:25 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00054] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:230 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00069] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:238 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:114 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x000cf] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:424 
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00018] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/MulticastDelegate.cs:70 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System/Delegate.cs:398 
  at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB (System.Object o, GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke (GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at GLib.ExceptionManager.RaiseUnhandledException(System.Exception e, Boolean is_terminal)
   at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback(IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data)
   at Gtk.Application.gtk_main()
   at Gtk.Application.Run()
   at Gtk3SharpTest.MainClass.Main(System.String[] args) in /media/Auslagerung/tmp/Gtk3-Sharp-Test/Gtk3-Sharp-Test/Program.cs:line 14

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gst.Pipeline ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gst.Pipeline:gstsharp_gst_pipeline_get_fixed_clock_offset ()
  at Gst.Pipeline..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:537 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gst.Pipeline ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libgstreamersharpglue-1.0.0.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gst.Pipeline:gstsharp_gst_pipeline_get_fixed_clock_offset ()
  at Gst.Pipeline..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /builddir/build/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:537
```

Anyone can help me, where I can find the dll? Or did I miss something in building?!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have libgstreamerglue-1.0.0 in your Output directory.

Comment: Correct, but I can't find it in the build from gstreamer-sharp, so where do I get this from?

Comment: I see, that it should be build with gstreamer-sharp but it didn't. When I run the "make" inside the "glue" directory, I get this errors:     generated.c: In function 'gst__tagssharp_gst__tags_tagdemux_get_element_offset':
generated.c:1092:2: error: unknown type name 'GstTagDemux'
  return (guint)G_STRUCT_OFFSET (GstTagDemux, element);
  ^
generated.c: In function 'gst__tagssharp_gst__tags_tagmux_get_element_offset':
generated.c:1100:2: error: unknown type name 'GstTagMux'
  return (guint)G_STRUCT_OFFSET (GstTagMux, element);
  ^

Comment: How can I build the glue library?

Comment: You need gstreamer-plugins-tag-1.0. If it doesn't come with your packages, you need to compile and install gstreamer from source.

Comment: On Ubuntu these headers are in libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev

Comment: @Sven, additionally, your problem was fixed at the configure level in this commit: https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp/commit/b47125ea7add014fc668c8815aa953887abf0702

Comment: I have tried to build version 0.99.x, so is this already included, or should I use the master branch?

Comment: 0.99.x? that is not a version number, please say what value x has?

Answer (score 0):

libgstreamersharpglue.so is located in a directory so far unknown to ldconfig.

I'm using ubuntu 15.04.
Open a command line and do the following:

ldconfig -p | grep libgstreamersharpglue   -> no output means it is not in ldconfig's cache

locate gstreamer | grep glue    (be sure to have done sudo updatedb)
-> if this doesn't produce output you don't have all the needed packages installed

if the file is somewhere on your system it will be in the resulting list:

for me it's /usr/lib/cli/gstreamer-sharp-0.9/libgstreamersharpglue-0.10.so

You need to make ldconfig use the /usr/lib/cli/gstreamer-sharp-0.9 directory.

OR:
add the directory as a line directly to /etc/ld.so.conf

OR:
drop a .conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d and add the directory to that file

on my system I did the latter:
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/cli.conf

with two records in it
/usr/lib/cli

/usr/lib/cli/gstreamer-sharp-0.9

now rebuild ldconfig's cache

sudo ldconfig

to test if it was succesful:

ldconfig -p | grep gstreamersharpglue  -> you should get output from this

Retry running your application