# Using GStreamer in Mono on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop, gstreamer

I want to use GStreamer for sound effects and music in a game.

Installed GStreamer from this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~ddalex/+archive/ubuntu/gstreamer

And also tried installing GStreamer this way, after installing it from the PPA did not appear to work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/279509/how-can-i-install-gstreamer-1-0-in-ubuntu-12-04

However, both times GStreamer installed correctly as far as I could tell, and yet it will not show up under references in MonoDevelop.

Is it possible that I have misunderstood how to use GStreamer in MonoDevelop?

EDIT: I have since downloaded GStreamer sharp:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gstreamer-sharp.html

But I don't understand how to use it, any help?

EDIT: To clarify, my operating system is Ubuntu 14.04

EDIT: I thought the the problem was solved.

Using apt-cache search 'gstreamer' I found and installed the library libgstreamer0.10-cil-dev, now GStreamer shows up in MonoDevelop!

However, while GStreamer now shows up in references, when I tried to compile a test program done in C# but based on the official GStreamer SDK tutorial.

The test program:

```
Gst.Element pipeline;

    Gst.Application.Init ();

    pipeline = Gst.Parse.Launch("playbin2 uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm");
    pipeline.SetState(Gst.State.Playing);
```

I get this error: `An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gst.GLib.GType`, under details it seems the problem is a missing library: `System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gst.GLib.GType ---> System.Exception: libgstreamersharpglue-0.10.so`

Thanks to otopolsky for their help in getting this far! And thanks in advance for any further help.

Update: The problem appears to be solved now, see the answer below for the solution.

Comment: you can try `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink`.. also you can check what says pkgconfig `pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0` it should show include paths etc, I also found [this one](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gstreamer-sharp.html)

Comment: I tried GStreamer sharp from the link you gave, but how do I use it in MonoDevelop? Do I compile it, or something else? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529130/how-to-build-gstreamer-1-0-c-sharp-net-bindings-on-windows-7 which has some little infos..

Comment: Thank you again. I completely forgot to add this, but my operating system is Ubuntu 14.04. Tried compiling with ./autogen.sh && make as in the link you gave, but it said "no package glib-sharp-3.0 found".

Comment: well then install that package :) maybe its this one.. libglib3.0-cil-dev, in worst case you would have to compile that .. or use older commit/branch of gstreamer-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

Using `apt-cache search 'gstreamer'` I found and installed the library `libgstreamer0.10-cil-dev`, now GStreamer shows up in MonoDevelop!

Thanks to otopolsky for their help.

EDIT: See the question above, I thought the problem was solved but another problem arose.

Update: The problem is solved! It turns out that the library `libgstreamersharpglue` was not in a directory known to ldconfig. Eventually I found this answer that explained how to have ldconfig use this directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32330648/5870433

Also of help was this site explaining how to add a library to ldconfig cache: https://codeyarns.com/2014/01/14/how-to-add-library-directory-to-ldconfig-cache/